# Sketch.js on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

Anyone knows how to make [sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) work properly on the iPad? It almost works perfectly, but the problem is that once you draw a line and do mouseUp, and you want to draw some more, it does that but it erases everything around the new line you are drawing.

Comment: Yeah just tried it on my iPad 2 and I experience the same behavior

Comment: ``It suffers significant performance degradation on mobile browsers due to general HTML5 Canvas performance issues.``, I guess Safari isn't fully HTML 5 compatible ..

Comment: I've noticed the issue too, it's definitely a bug. I plan to look into it when I have a chance but that may not be until the middle of next week sometime. I need to rework the drawing algorithm to redraw less frequently and reset the canvas using a different trick than the current one it's using. Keep tuned to the repository for the fixes.

Comment: Thanks Michael, any news on this?

Comment: Michael, someone posted a work around for this on github, which solved the problem. You might want to look into it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@leonth, posted a workaround for this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js/issues/1) which solved the problem for me.